# Automating web application in selenium with python

Tags: selenium

This is my code where all things are alright but at last when i click on save button its not working. I have tried accessing element by id, name, xpath and class name of the save button but click for save not working. When that part need to executed nothing happen.Rest of the program executing properly.Plz suggest

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    import time
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"C:\Users\mvintee\project_for_selenium\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    driver.get("http://pis033/NorthStarWMS/User/PurchaseOrders.aspx?t=1&PO=1")
    print(driver.title)
    driver.find_element("id","Login1_UserName").send_keys("wms")
    driver.find_element("id","Login1_Password").send_keys("1")
    driver.find_element("class name","rbText").click()
    
    time.sleep(5)
    element_to_hover_over=driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="ctl00_MenuTabNew"]/ul/li[4]/span/span')
    time.sleep(5)
    
    hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
    hover.perform()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="ctl00_MenuTabNew"]/ul/li[4]/div/ul/li[1]/a/span').click()
    #time.sleep(5)
    
    driver.find_element("id","ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ShipOrderGrid_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_btnAdd").click()
    
    #time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element("class name",'RadButton RadButton_Hay rbLinkButton btn_new_bg_popUpnew').click()
    #time.sleep(5)
    
    element=driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="btnSave"]').click()
    
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    import time
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"C:\Users\mvintee\project_for_selenium\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    driver.get("http://pis033/NorthStarWMS/User/PurchaseOrders.aspx?t=1&PO=1")
    print(driver.title)
    driver.find_element("id","Login1_UserName").send_keys("wms")
    driver.find_element("id","Login1_Password").send_keys("1")
    driver.find_element("class name","rbText").click()
    
    time.sleep(5)
    element_to_hover_over=driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="ctl00_MenuTabNew"]/ul/li[4]/span/span')
    time.sleep(5)
    
    hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
    hover.perform()
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="ctl00_MenuTabNew"]/ul/li[4]/div/ul/li[1]/a/span').click()
    #time.sleep(5)
    
    driver.find_element("id","ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ShipOrderGrid_ctl00_ctl02_ctl00_btnAdd").click()
    
    #time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element("class name",'RadButton RadButton_Hay rbLinkButton btn_new_bg_popUpnew').click()
    #time.sleep(5)
    
    element=driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="btnSave"]').click()
```

Comment: Could you check the URL again? It's not accessible

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.